# Crashes in onPauseState

Tags: android, android-activity, illegalstateexception

My activity crashes when I pause it. I could see from the logs, it is failing at saveInstance. I am not sure how to fix it.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {           
        NavFragment navListFragment = (NavFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Const.TAG_FRAGMENT_NAV);   
        if (navListFragment != null)
        {
            savedInstanceState.putInt(Const.STATE_VAR_NAV_INDEX, navListFragment.getSelection());
            Log.i("STATE", "navListFragment.getSelection(): " + navListFragment.getSelection());
        }

        Fragment contentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Const.TAG_FRAGMENT_CONTENT);
        if(contentFragment != null && contentFragment instanceof BasicContentFragment)
        {                       
            savedInstanceState.putBoolean(Const.STATE_VAR_IS_CONTENT, true);
            savedInstanceState.putInt(Const.STATE_VAR_CONTENT_INDEX, ((BasicContentFragment)contentFragment).getCurrentPage());

            if(Const.IS_LARGE_SCREEN)
            {
                SlidingDrawer drawer = (SlidingDrawer)findViewById(R.id.selector_drawer);
                if(drawer != null)              
                    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(Const.STATE_VAR_IS_LIST_VISIBLE, drawer.isOpened());                          
            }
        }

        savedInstanceState.putString(Const.STATE_VAR_HEADING, mHeading);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); // crashes in this line
    }
```

Logs:

```
02-04 10:50:20.320: E/AndroidRuntime(23650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 10:50:20.320: E/AndroidRuntime(23650): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: active DialogFactory{407dd070} has cleared index: -1
02-04 10:50:20.320: E/AndroidRuntime(23650): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1695)
02-04 10:50:20.320: E/AndroidRuntime(23650): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:499)
02-04 10:50:20.320: E/AndroidRuntime(23650): at com.philly.prosportsframework.activity.MainFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(MainFragmentActivity.java:625)
```

Comment: try put the call of the `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` method to the first line of you `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
` method.

Comment: do you have any dialog fragments? (DialogFactory?), problem might be similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819460/dialogfragment-crashes-activity-when-calling-startactivity

Comment: simekadam - I tried to place as you mentioned, still didn't work

Comment: marcin_j - yes there is fragment called DialogFactory.

Comment: We are supposed to get RSS feed and display them. Others work fine. I modified for one to show navigation in the feed. Some of the changes I did was to call the Aysnc task in a loop. for (int i=0;i<contentOf.size();i++)
   { RefreshTask refreshTask = new RefreshTask(this, getHandler(), mFeed, lastModified); 
     refreshTask.execute();
     contentOf.get(i).mFeed = mFeed;}. Could this be a problem. I am able to see the data, but when its paused it crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly looks like there is a "leftover" after the `DialogFactory` `Fragment` in `FragmentManager`, but the `Fragment` itself has it's state already cleared. So when the `FragmentManager` tries to save the state, it fails.

Try to explicitly remove the `DialogFactory` from `FragmentManager` via the [`FragmentTransaction.remove(Fragment fragment)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove%28android.app.Fragment%29) method. If it didn't help try to call [`FragmentManager.executePendingTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29) before saving the state (and after commiting the remove transaction).

Comment: I am not able to see the issue now, donno why. If its reproducible, I will try the steps you mentioned.